# Copy multiple ranges to compile on separate sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've googled this multiple times and read a ton of articles, but I'm not having any luck making this work.

Sheets("Source") columns B, C, D, Q,R,S, and AF, AG, AH need to be copied to Sheets("Destination") and pasted to B, C,D, M,N,O and X,Y,Z respectively. The snag is that the other columns in the destination sheet have formulas in then then well calculate based off the data in the ranges to paste.  The idea is to have the source ranges (who are also named ranges, if that helps) copy and continually compile to the destination page before the workbook closes.

I've been able to get a range of two columns to work but three or more seems to cause a problem.  Any advice?

```
Sub Rectangle4_Click()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim copySheet As Worksheet
  Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
  Set copySheet = Worksheets("Source")
  Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Destination")
  copySheet.Range("Actual_value1").Copy
  pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If you leave ScreenUpdating alone, does the problem get clearer? Are you getting any errors? What's the problem, specifically?

Comment: I suspect you want to disable application events before you start copying stuff around, and restore it after - otherwise you have Excel recalcs interfering.

Comment: I removed the screen updating and adding additional lines for the extra ranges and it seems to be working now.  Thanks so much for the advice!